# How to get the data usage of a specific AWS service

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I was trying to find how to check monthly data usage of a specific AWS service (eg. EC2) but I don't seem to get my head around it:

I tried this dashboard:

So for example, I was looking at the data usage from year 2019 to 2013 on a per month basis.

I tried to do 2019 first.

I press the **Download** button and selected the CSV report format.

[image]

I then open the downloaded CSV report via Microsoft Excel

[image]

If I format the **UsageValue** column to use Numbers, below is what is the output:

[image]

So now, does the UsageValue in **GB** or **TB**? How does one actually compute the data usage based on this output?

Thank you in advance!

**EDIT**

To be more clear, in what size unit the numbers below **UsageValue** indicates? Is it in Bytes, GB or TB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The “UsageType” column tells you, typically. In the snippet you have shared, some can easily be seen to show that they are Bytes.

If you have a question about a specific one, might I suggest editing your question with text containing the full readout, so we will know exactly which one is in question?

Comment: thank you for the answer. Edited my question too. How does one determine if it's indeed in Byte size unit?

Comment: thank you @ackack. I understand now. Like it says in the UsageType, APS1-NatGateway-Bytes. But how does one compute it for a monthly basis data usage?

Comment: It’s in Bytes, and in your screenshot it already shows that it’s computing for a range between Jan 1, 2019, and Feb 1, 2019. Convert the bytes value to MB or GB and you’ll have the format you want.